# Falha de instalação de sdk android tools

Tags: android-sdk

Ao instalar pacotes do  Android SDK *tools*, aparece essa mensagem e a instalação, obviamente, é interrompida:

> Failed to rename directory
>   D:\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\tools to
>   D:\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\temp\ToolPackage.old01.

Alguém aí sabe como resolver isso? Obrigado desde já pela força.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai algumas sugestões para o problema:

- Executar como **administrador**;
- Tenha certeza que nem **Eclipse**, nem **Android Studio** estejam abertos;
- Execute pela linha de comando;
- Faça uma cópia da pasta `tools`, renomeie-a para algo como `cópia` e execute o comando a partir dessa nova pasta;
- Exclua todo o conteúdo da pasta `D:\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\temp`